# How to structure/normalize this database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

I need to make a database that should hold 50 questions, 3 possible answers for each question and value of each answer.

[image]

This is my first guess but it feels wrong and I'm not sure how to access this values properly.
Any suggestions on how to structure this?

This seems like correct way:

```
questions table
---------------
id
title
...

answers table
-------------
id
question_id
answer
value
```

Comment: The value should probably just be a field of the associated answer's record.

Comment: The only reason I would think to have the values in a separate table would be if the same values were used across multiple answers AND there was defined need to have be that if the value were changed, it would be for all answers that used it.

Comment: True, true -  I was just thinking of that.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
questions table
---------------
id
title
...

values table
------------
id
value


answers table
-------------
id
question_id
answer
value_id
```

Then to get all answers of a specific question do

```
select a.*, v.value
from answers a
join questions q on q.id = a.question_id
join values v on v.id = a.value_id
where q.title = 'what is the name of Dr. Who'
```

Comment: Tnx for making queries. I'm testing this

Answer (score 0):

```
questions 
----------
id
title

answers 
--------
id
question_id
answer
value
```

This query would give you all the questions with their possible answers, with the answers listed from best to worst (assuming `value` is a "points" system, and not a description of quality like "Good" "Better" "Best").

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions AS qTbl 
LEFT JOIN answers AS aTbl ON qTbl.id = aTbl.question_id
ORDER BY qTbl.title, aTbl.value DESC
;
```

Comment: Would I be a dick If I asked for query?

Comment: @user3188464 No, but you'd need to specify what exactly you want the query to show. I'll add a standard "flattened view" one to start.

Comment: value is an integer from 0-100 but I get it, tnx - best answer